# How to control multiple processes using multi-threaded single process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, multiprocessing, pexpect

I have an application which requires multiple processes to be forked and controlled from single process(multithreading is done to communicate with each of them) - a kind of server-client model.

One of the solutions available is using PExpect. But the problem with PExpect is that there is no support for multithreading. 
Suppose I want to open multiple instances of GDB and invoke parallel debugging, PExpect complicates the communication between these different instances of GDB with the main initiating process which needs to control different GDB instances all the time in terms of synchronization, consistency etc. Multithreading support has many advantages like sharing objects, memory etc .

So, I would like to know if any support available in python such that I can use threads and each thread can handle the individual instances of the GDB. The advantage is that, multiple threads belonging to single process makes communication simpler.

I want a replacement for PExpect which support multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Python [Multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module is an excellent library for multitasking application. It is a server/parent - client/child model where server can send jobs to X number of clients and the results will be collected back from client process asynchronously. And even you can configure it to create child processes which gets killed and respawned after N number of operations.

Comment: @prabhuvishnumurthy can you mark my answer as correct if it helped you ?